# Check all with specific value in checkbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I got some problem when I want to develope checkall function using jquery.

I put all checkboxes in table to make it clear and would like to check all checkbox with value in `input`.

For example, when I click the checkbox with value `type1`, then all checkboxes value including `type1` will be checked as well (type1, type1-1 and type 1-2).

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr class='type1'>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="type1"></td>
      <td>Type_1<td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='type1-1'>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="type1-1"></td>
      <td>Type_1-1<td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='type1-2'>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="type1-2"></td>
      <td>Type_1-2<td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='type2'>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="type2"></td>
      <td>Type_2<td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='type2-1'>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="type2-1"></td>
      <td>Type_2-1<td>
    </tr>        
</table>
```

Is it possible to do it with jquery?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$(':checkbox').change(function() { 
   var chkValue=$(this).attr("value");   
   if($(this).is(':checked'))
   {    
      $(':checkbox[value*="'+chkValue+'"]').prop('checked', true);
      //use selector^= OR selector*= as per your need
   }
   else
   {
      $(':checkbox[value*="'+chkValue+'"]').prop('checked', false);
   }
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nb53e79w/1/)